# How do I complete Lesson 10 of the Basic Lessons?

Tags: pushmo

I am playing Pushmo on the 3DS and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to complete level 10. There does not seem to be a way to pull out the last block at the top to save the little Pushmo kid that is trapped there.

The only help I get is the old man telling me to "pull the lowest block all the way out" and to "try a side pull if I get stuck." Problem is, I don't know where to go from there.

How do I complete Lesson 10 of the Basic Lessons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you're not the only one who [got stuck](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/644719-pushmo/61289154):

> 1. Pull out the first block three times
> 2. Pull the second block twice
> 3. Jump on the second block
> 4. Pull out the small block on the left
> 5. Move to the side and pull it
> 6. Move back to were you first pulled the small block on the left and pull again.
>
> The trick is the "Side Pull" of the "Left Small Block". You must do 2 side pulls on it and then you should be able to pull out the top two long blocks to reach the goal.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that you could do the side pull from somewhere other than the end of a block. That helps!